# How does Chrome generate thumb views of URLs?

Tags: url, google-chrome, thumbnails

How does Chrome browser capture a thumbnail image of most visited URLs and show me over a blank page under Most visited??

- I am interested in knowing how I would implement it using for my website or an extension.. to take take screenshot.
- Lalith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write an extension that captures a screenshot of a current site then there is  [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) method.

Comment: @Lalith then it is not easy task.

Answer (score 2):

I can only tell you how would I implement it. Once you would go to a site, I will add 1 to a counter if how many times you've entered it. If it's in the top 10, I would also take a screen shot of the site (chrome has a window in the class "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND" which is the window that only contains the site, not the buttons and menus around it).
I can only guess it's not too far from what the guys in Google did.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it takes a screenshot from the last time you visited the page and saves it in the "Top Sites" SQLite database file that can be found in your profile folder.