# How does Firefox generate page thumbnails for new tab page?

Tags: javascript, thumbnails

In Firefox, the default new tab page contains a list of web page recommendations with the page domain name as well as a thumbnail. The thumbnail can be either be a favicon if it is large enough, or a preview image of the web page. Such as this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdAqj.png).

I am trying to create my own version of new tab page with thumbnails similar to Firefox's. Most of the solutions in the Internet suggest to deploy a server (e.g. [via node.js](https://github.com/talmobi/quick-shot)) or use a service (e.g. [URL2PNG](https://www.url2png.com/)).

Therefore, I am curious how Firefox generate the thumbnails client-side (please correct me if it is actually server-side). Are there any recommended libraries/frameworks (e.g. [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) although it cannot screenshot other websites)?

Comment: Maybe usefull for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700606/how-does-chrome-generate-thumb-views-of-urls?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: "*I am trying to create my own start page*" start page of what? Ps: the browser did display this page, so it's quite easy for it to take a snapshot, and even though I'm not sure they use this for the thumbnails, you might be interested in https://github.com/mozilla-services/screenshots

Comment: @Kaiido I mean my own version of new tab page, gonna edit that and take a look into the link. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @Ezhno The question is similar to mine but based on Chrome. Sadly I think Firefox can't use Chrome's libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how useful this is for your case but it renders a snapshot of a window to an intermediate canvas using the (non-standard, internal) [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawWindow() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow), then copies that to a target downscaled canvas element.

You can see the code that does this in [toolkit/components/thumbnails/PageThumbUtils.jsm](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/thumbnails/PageThumbUtils.jsm):

```
  /** *
   * Given a browser window, this creates a snapshot of the content
   * and returns a canvas with the resulting snapshot of the content
   * at the thumbnail size. It has to do this through a two step process:
   *
   * 1) Render the content at the window size to a canvas that is 2x the thumbnail size
   * 2) Downscale the canvas from (1) down to the thumbnail size
   *
   * This is because the thumbnail size is too small to render at directly,
   * causing pages to believe the browser is a small resolution. Also,
   * at that resolution, graphical artifacts / text become very jagged.
   * It's actually better to the eye to have small blurry text than sharp
   * jagged pixels to represent text.
   *
   * @params aWindow - the window to create a snapshot of.
   * @params aDestCanvas destination canvas to draw the final
   *   snapshot to. Can be null.
   * @param aArgs (optional) Additional named parameters:
   *   fullScale - request that a non-downscaled image be returned.
   * @return Canvas with a scaled thumbnail of the window.
   */
  createSnapshotThumbnail(aWindow, aDestCanvas, aArgs) {
    if (Cu.isCrossProcessWrapper(aWindow)) {
      throw new Error("Do not pass cpows here.");
    }
    let fullScale = aArgs ? aArgs.fullScale : false;
    let [contentWidth, contentHeight] = this.getContentSize(aWindow);
    let [thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight] = aDestCanvas ?
                                            [aDestCanvas.width, aDestCanvas.height] :
                                            this.getThumbnailSize(aWindow);

    // If the caller wants a fullscale image, set the desired thumbnail dims
    // to the dims of content and (if provided) size the incoming canvas to
    // support our results.
    if (fullScale) {
      thumbnailWidth = contentWidth;
      thumbnailHeight = contentHeight;
      if (aDestCanvas) {
        aDestCanvas.width = contentWidth;
        aDestCanvas.height = contentHeight;
      }
    }

    let intermediateWidth = thumbnailWidth * 2;
    let intermediateHeight = thumbnailHeight * 2;
    let skipDownscale = false;

    // If the intermediate thumbnail is larger than content dims (hiDPI
    // devices can experience this) or a full preview is requested render
    // at the final thumbnail size.
    if ((intermediateWidth >= contentWidth ||
         intermediateHeight >= contentHeight) || fullScale) {
      intermediateWidth = thumbnailWidth;
      intermediateHeight = thumbnailHeight;
      skipDownscale = true;
    }

    // Create an intermediate surface
    let snapshotCanvas = this.createCanvas(aWindow, intermediateWidth,
                                           intermediateHeight);

    // Step 1: capture the image at the intermediate dims. For thumbnails
    // this is twice the thumbnail size, for fullScale images this is at
    // content dims.
    // Also by default, canvas does not draw the scrollbars, so no need to
    // remove the scrollbar sizes.
    let scale = Math.min(Math.max(intermediateWidth / contentWidth,
                                  intermediateHeight / contentHeight), 1);

    let snapshotCtx = snapshotCanvas.getContext("2d");
    snapshotCtx.save();
    snapshotCtx.scale(scale, scale);
    snapshotCtx.drawWindow(aWindow, 0, 0, contentWidth, contentHeight,
                           PageThumbUtils.THUMBNAIL_BG_COLOR,
                           snapshotCtx.DRAWWINDOW_DO_NOT_FLUSH);
    snapshotCtx.restore();

    // Part 2: Downscale from our intermediate dims to the final thumbnail
    // dims and copy the result to aDestCanvas. If the caller didn't
    // provide a target canvas, create a new canvas and return it.
    let finalCanvas = aDestCanvas ||
      this.createCanvas(aWindow, thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight);

    let finalCtx = finalCanvas.getContext("2d");
    finalCtx.save();
    if (!skipDownscale) {
      finalCtx.scale(0.5, 0.5);
    }
    finalCtx.drawImage(snapshotCanvas, 0, 0);
    finalCtx.restore();

    return finalCanvas;
  },
```

Comment: This is surely helpful! By "internal privileged APIs", does it mean it cannot be accessed normally by other scripts such as the ones in a web page?

Comment: Yep, the internal API it uses is this one:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow

(edited answer to include this)